# Replace the text of span element

Tags: javascript, replace, entity

I want to replace the square icon (text in span element in html file: ■) with an arrow one: ►. It happens when this icon in front of a menu item matches its page ID so the visitor knows he is on the page indicated by this menu item.

I've been through many issues but stuck with this one.

```
var newIcon = "&#9658;"; // arrow icon
for (var j = 0; j < rightMenuIDs.length; j++){
    var thisID = rightMenuIDs[j];
    var thisSpanIcon = rightMenu[j].children[0].children[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    if(thisID === bodyIDsliced){
        thisSpanIcon = newIcon;
    }
}
```

I checked with console.log, it says thisSpanIcon has been updated as the arrow icon. But nothing has changed on the page. 
I tried replace() and other methods to no avail.

Can someone lay on me if there's a better / correct way to do this?

thanks!

Comment: We need to know what those variables are representing.

Comment: The variable is getting changed but the content on the page is not.  This should work: `rightMenu[j].children[0].children[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue=newIcon;`  Or you can set `thisSpanIcon=rightMenu[j].children[0].children[0].childNodes[0]` and then `thisSpanIcon.nodeValue=newIcon`

Comment: @Jivings no, it's pretty obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

```
thisSpanIcon = newIcon;
```

you're just overwriting the local variable `thisSpanIcon` which contains a *copy* of the node's existing `nodeValue` property, not changing the property (and thence the node) itself.

Try:

```
var thisSpanNode = rightMenu[j].children[0].children[0].childNodes[0];
if (thisID === bodyIDsliced) {
    thisSpanNode.nodeValue = newIcon;
}
```

which should change the actual property of the node instead.

Also note that you should use Unicode format for the string instead of an HTML entity, i.e. `\u25ba`.

Comment: That's some revelation. I guess that's some nuance I would have to spend some time mulling over it.

Comment: If may I continue this topic slightly astray: &#9658; doesn't really come out nicely as a solid right arrow. Is it just how I put the entity or I have to use "icon font" to fix this?

Comment: no idea, it'll depend on what system you have.  Try looking at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25ba/fontsupport.htm

Answer (score -1):

You must work with [`elem.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) or `elem.innerText` to update the text of an element/node. ([little example](http://jsfiddle.net/hSxtS/1/))

Also, search for some modern way of selecting elements.

Comment: `node.nodeValue` is perfectly legal.

Comment: Thanks for the selecting advice @Wouter J I just started practicing JavaScript. So I thought it's better start with some old school way to make sure I get the foundation right.

Comment: @cybercow69 good plan - to properly understand e.g. jQuery, it's much better to first understand native DOM traversal.

Comment: @Alnitak I fully agree with you! (I didn't suggested jQuery or something like that)

Comment: However, I don't understand the downvote? This answer is just a correct answer to the question, you can also use `nodeValue`, but `innerText` works too?

Comment: The example of elem.innerHTML and element.innerText is interesting. It might help me resolve the issue of displaying right arrow.

Comment: it's because you said he _must_ use those, when in fact `.nodeValue` is a valid and correct W3C property and when nothing else in the answer actually relates to the fundamental flaw in the OP's code (i.e. trying to modify a local variable instead of a property)

Comment: @cybercow69 that issue should be addressed in a new question.

Comment: `.nodeValue` is correct if the node is a text node.  `.innerHTML` and `.innerText` are only correct if the node in question is the one _enclosing_ the text node.  The OP needs the former.  See http://jsfiddle.net/xrZLQ/